# Unable to run nginx inside docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, docker-in-docker

I am trying to run an nginx image inside a Docker container. I have tried these steps

- ssh inside ubuntu docker image `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it ubuntu:latest bash`
- Installed  [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/)
- Run Nginx image `docker run  -d -p 80:80 nginx`

`curl localhost:80` gives `Connection refused`

Comment: Why are you trying to `docker run` from inside of ubuntu container?

Answer (score 0):

Mapping `docker.sock` to containers means you will be using the docker daemon of **the host machine**, not the container's.

So when you run `docker run  -d -p 80:80 nginx` command, the nginx container is created and run in host machine (sibling of the ubuntu container). Hence, `80:80` maps in the host machine.

Validate this by running `docker ps` in ubuntu container and in the host machine. The result should match. And I guess, you can do `curl localhost` in the host machine and hit the nginx server as well.

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer does answer your question, please mark it as correct.